# How to fix AttributeError in python when calling function in fucntion?

Tags: python

I want to write in a DB Table new Google Analytics accounts if there are any.

There are 5 functions executing in a row, one after each other:

1. `db_connection()` - connect to DataBase
2. `get_current_sql_account_table()` - fetches actual SQL table with Google Analytics accounts in dataframe format
3. `get_account_list()` - gets GA accounts list and converts it in dataframe
4. `compare_df()` - compares 2 dataframes and if there are new GA accounts writes them in DB with this function
5. `write_new_accounts_to_DB()`

And the GA Service Key credentials put in variables.

The code itself works ok, but when it was wrapped into functions and executed I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

1. `db_connection()`
2. `get_current_sql_account_table()` ======== Here is the problem
3. `get_account_list()`
4. `compare_df()`
5. `write_new_accounts_to_DB()`

`cursor` is defined in the `get_current_sql_account_table()` function:

```py
def db_connection():

    #set parameters for connecting with the DB
    config = dict(server='Server', 
              port=Port,
              database='DB',
              username='User',
              password='Pass')

    #set parameters
    conn_str = ('SERVER={server},{port};'   +
            'DATABASE={database};'      +
            'UID={username};'           +
            'PWD={password}')

    #connect to DB
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={Driver};' +
        conn_str.format(**config)
    )

    #open the cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I've tried to pass a `db_connection` as a parameter in `get_current_sql_account_table()` function:

```py
def get_current_sql_account_table(conn):
    conn=db_connection
    sql_table_current = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Table', con=conn)
    return sql_table_current
```

But got the same error

Then I've tried to run everything, but db config not in a function and have another error

```
NameError: name 'sql_table_current' is not defined.
```

The I put everything in main:

```py
def main():
    sql_table_current_table=get_current_sql_account_table()
    accounts_response=get_account_list()
    conn=db_connection()
    compare_df()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And have this error `TypeError: compare_df() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'sql_table_current_table' and 'accounts_response'`.

I understand that there is a stupid mistake but can't get where

## UPDATED

When I tried tio run this code

```
def main():

    sql_table_current_table=get_current_sql_account_table()
    accounts_response=get_account_list()
    conn=db_connection()
    compare_df()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Got this error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4c89335f4c9b> in <module>
     21 
     22 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 23     main()

<ipython-input-10-4c89335f4c9b> in main()
      8     logging.info('Finished')
      9 
---> 10     sql_table_current_table=get_current_sql_account_table()
     11     accounts_response=get_account_list()
     12     conn=db_connection()

<ipython-input-2-92eb504dec52> in get_current_sql_account_table()
      1 def get_current_sql_account_table():
----> 2     sql_table_current = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Table', con=conn)
      3     return sql_table_current

NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

But i did put conn=db_connection() like this before

Comment: A full stack-trace would be helpful to diagnose where the problem lies, and what function-call that is triggering the exception.

Comment: Sorry, we need clearer error information. What is the full traceback? If the traceback ends in the `cursor = conn.cursor()` line, then `conn` was `None`, and that would indicate that `pyodbc.connect()` returned `None`. That is unlikely however (I'd expect that function to return a `Connection` instance or raise an exception).

Comment: Hello, I added more info about the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to name cursor as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your db_connection() function does not return anything so in your statement conn = db_connection(), conn has no value. There are other potential errors in your code.